# Queue: Enqueue vs Dequeue (Fill out table, Shift needed?)

Tags: java, python, data-structures, queue, enqueue

I'm filling out this table and wondering if I did it right:

[image: Table to fill out]

We learned it like this:
dequeue(Q) -> returns most front (right-hand) element
enqueue(Q,k) -> inserts k as new most rear (left-hand) element

I'm kinda unsure because I have to make a shift, when I want to enqueue a new item (all other items shift by one to the front), is that correct?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This diagram is correct for one implementation of the queue data structure.

If the row of boxes represents a fixed size array, it's not a very efficient implementation because of the shifting as you've observed. A different implementation called [circular queue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) removes the need to shift items.